# Booting KDE on Chromebook 14

Tags: kde, startup

I have installed KDE on my HP Chromebook 14.

I am, however, having difficulty with setting KDE as the default startup window manager.

Comment: When you boot into Linux, are you presented with a graphical login screen or are you delivered straight into your desktop?

Comment: @KlaatuvonSchlacker I get the Chrome OS verification warning screen before it boots back into Chrome. Then I have to run `sudo startkde` command to load back into KDE

Answer (score 0):

KDE is a desktop environment (DE), not a window manager. The built-in window manager KDE uses is called Kwin. I think you want to set up KDE as your DE however, which gets started either by the "startx" command out of a tty session, where you have to edit your ~.xinitrc or the gui way with a display manager like lightdm or KDM which can be used to graphically log in to your account. You have check which option you use and adjust the appropriate config file (look it up on the internet).